# MPI hang on persistance calling

Tags: c, mpi

I am trying to implement some form of persistent calling. Somehow the following code keeps hanging - I guessed I must have introduced a deadlock but can't really wrap my head around it...

```
MPI_Request r[4];
[...]
MPI_Send_init(&Arr[1][1], 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, A, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &r[0]);
MPI_Recv_init(&Arr[1][0], 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, A, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &r[1]);

MPI_Send_init(&Arr[2][1], 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, B, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &r[2]);
MPI_Recv_init(&Arr[2][0], 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, B, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &r[3]);
[...]
MPI_Startall(4, r);
MPI_Waitall(4, r, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
```

I think this is perfect material for deadlock - what would be the remedy here if I want to init these send/receive message and just invoke the processes later all with `Startall` and `Waitall`?

**EDIT**: So if I do

```
MPI_Start(&r[0]);
MPI_Wait(&r[0], &status):
```

Then it does not hang. Invoking something like:

```
for (int k=0; k<1; k++)
  {
    MPI_Start(&r[k]);
    MPI_Wait(&r[k], &status);
  }
```

fail and hang. if that helps

Answer (score 1):

your tags do not match.

for example, rank `0` receives from itself with tag `A`
but it sends to itself with tag `B`

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit I'm not familiar with the concept of MPI requests and the *MPI_Send/Recv_init*. However, I could reproduce the deadlock with simple sends and receives. This is the code (it has a deadlock):

```
double someVal = 3.5;
const int MY_FIRST_TAG = 42;
MPI_Send(&someVal, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, MY_FIRST_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Recv(&someVal, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MY_FIRST_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

Even if you run it with only two processes, the problem is the following: Both, process 0 and 1 send a message to process 1. Then both processes want to receive a message from process 0. Process 1 can because process zero actually sent a message to process 1. But nobody sent a message to process 0. Consequently, this process will wait there forever.

How to fix: You need to specify that only process 0 sends to process 1 and only process 1 is supposed to receive from process 0. You can simply do it with:

```
int rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
if (rank == 0)
    MPI_Send(&someVal, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, MY_FIRST_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
else // Assumption: Only two processes
    MPI_Recv(&someVal, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MY_FIRST_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

I'm not 100% sure how to translate this to the concept of requests and *MPI_Send/Recv_init* but maybe this helps you nonetheless.